# Neo4J Cypher grabbing type of relations when using variable length paths

Tags: neo4j, cypher

query:

```
Match (d:User {name:"User"}) -[r:IS_MEMBER_OF]->(g:Group:Local) - [r1:IS_SUBGROUP_OF*0..]->(g1:Group) Return type(r), type(r1)
```

the cypher command type is valid for the relation without variable length paths but not valid for the variable ones even when they have the same name. How would I grab the name (type) of r1 as return from the query?

Thanks,
B

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there seems to be [a bug](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues/4583) in version 2.2.1 (and maybe some earlier versions) that prevents this from working:

```
MATCH (:User { name:"User" })-[r:IS_MEMBER_OF]->(:Group:Local)-[r1:IS_SUBGROUP_OF*0..]->(:Group)
RETURN type(r), EXTRACT(rel IN r1 | type(rel)) AS ancestorGroupTypes;
```

So, this is a workaround until the above simpler query works again:

```
MATCH p=(:User {name:"User"})-[r:IS_MEMBER_OF]->(:Group:Local)-[r1:IS_SUBGROUP_OF*0..]->(:Group)
Return type(r), EXTRACT (rel IN TAIL(RELATIONSHIPS(p)) | type(rel)) AS ancestorGroupTypes;
```

Comment: That makes sense, thank you. I tried it but run into an issues: "Expected `r1` to be a Collection<Any> but it was a Relationship". I was assuming that 'r1' would be all the relations on the path, so I am unsure where the issue might be.

Comment: Yes, there seems to be a bug. I have added a workaround to my answer.

Comment: Yep, now it works as expected. Thanks very much for your effort!